# Solução para GetRange error ao acessar elementos fora da lista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Ao chamar o `GetRange` de uma lista, onde chama 10 em 10 valores da lista por vez, porem da o seguinte erro:

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater
>   than the number of elements from index to the end of the source
>   collection.

Como ele chama de 10 em 10 se acabar a lista e nao conter os 10 ele acontece o erro, como posso fazer para que ao chamar 10 se não conter os 10 dentro da lista ele pega o restante que conter assim evitando o erro.

```
 foreach (var item in lst.GetRange(count, index))
        {
          //count e index e incrementado +10 quando passa novamente começa do (0,9)
         //aqui inseri os valores no cshtml
        }
```

Comment: E  pq dentro do foreach estou escrevento um html onde pega os valores do item e seta no value das tag e faz o retorno para um ajax em forma de html

Comment: Poderia postar o restante do código? Talvez o `Skip()` e `Take()` pode lhe atender melhor. De onde está vindo os valores de `count` e de `index`? O que você realmente deseja fazer? Talvez tenha uma alternativa melhor

Comment: De forma geral :  Esse for esta dentro deste metodo ObterConteudoIndex(int countIndex, int index) ,na view tem um ajax que e executado se o $('window.scroll')  chegar no final da pagina.  Que chama a função  url: '/ObterConteudoIndex?countIndex='+countIndex+'&index='+index+'', esse valores count e index são passado via parametro para o metodo pelo js , dentro do metodo ObterConteudoIndex eu percorro o banco de dados e pego os valores e salvo nessa lista "lst", quero que ele busca de 10 em 10 nessa lista enquanto ouver dados nela, esta tudo funcionando porem ele esta saindo fora da lista.

Comment: Então eu faria com `.Take()` e `.Skip()`. Seu exemplo ficaria algo como isso: `var listaNova = lst.Skip(10).Take(10).ToList()`;`. Nesse caso ele pularia 10 itens e iria obter os próximos 10. Um exemplo seria [isso daqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TfVk2B)

Comment: Realmente com take e skip funcionou perfeitamente quando ele acaba os itens e tenta acessar fora da lista ele nao da erro apenas retorna em branco :) Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está claro, como você mesmo disse. Com o `.GetRange()` você está passando o valor superior a quantidade de itens da lista.

Para continuar utilizando `.GetRange()`, você teria que tratar para isso não ocorrer.

Porém, pelo que você explicou [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156536/solu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-getrange-error-ao-acessar-elementos-fora-da-lista?noredirect=1#comment322822_156536), creio que o [.Take()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) e [.Skip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) pode lhe atender melhor.

> **.Take()**
> Retorna um número especificado de elementos contíguos do início de uma sequência.
>
> **.Skip()**
> Ignora um número especificado de elementos em uma sequência e, em seguida, retorna os elementos restantes.

Um exemplo com a utilização seria:

```
lst.Skip(10).Take(10).ToList()
```

Onde o `.Skip()` está "pulando" 10 itens e o `.Take()` está selecionando os próximos 10 itens.